# Sticky navbar has a bug on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have two sticky navbars, the first white one from `Wordpress` with its own sticky function, and the black one below is `html/css-only` (no bootstrap), and it has a strange movement on mobile, it's hard to explain so let me show you:

When I first load the page, it looks good like this:

But when I scroll down, even if just a little bit, the black navbar kind of bounces suddenly and very quickly and makes the content "jump". I have no idea why this is happening since there is no bug when loading the `webpage` from a computer! It's only a matter of mobile phones. :S

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
      jQuery('#navbar_reservas').addClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() <= 0) {
      jQuery('#navbar_reservas').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.navbar-fixed {
    top: 60px;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="navbar_reservas">
    <div id="reservas_left">
        <div class="nav-item_reservas" id="inner_reservas_left">
              <a id="dudas" href="tel:55555555">
                    ¿Dudas?
                    <br />555 555 555                 </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="reservas_right">
        <div class="dropdown_reservas nav-item_reservas" id="inner_reservas_right">
          <div class="dropbtn">
            TOTAL
            <br /><span id="totalprice">0,00€</span>
            <i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-content_reservas" id="myDropdown">
        <ul id="dropul" class="unoul">
          <li id="drop2"></li>
          <li id="drop3"></li>
          <li id="drop4"></li>
          <li id="drop5"></li>
          <li id="drop6"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you only add the `position: fixed` when `scrollTop` is not `0`. That will create a new stacking context when the class is applied. That means it'll no longer be "visible" to the elements around it in terms of positioning. And as such the content below it will jump up to fill the gap.

**If you know the height of the navbar already, there is a really simple solution:**

When the navbar do not have the `navbar-fixed` class, apply `position: absolute` on it so it's always in its own stacking context. Then add the height of the navbar as top padding/margin to the content below it.

**If you do not know the height:**

You'll need to do the same as above, but calculate the height of it with JavaScript on load. If it changes height on say resize or you have some dynamically changing content, you'll need to make sure to update the height used for the above method when those events happen.

**If you can work with relatively new code:**

There is a CSS property for all this! `position: sticky` combined with `top: 0` Will make the navbar stick to the top of the screen when it otherwise would scroll *up* behind the viewport.

However, browser support isn't very impressive:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked!!! I knew the height so I did the position:absolute thing. You're a life savior, Sir!!

Comment: @JJCarlk3 Updated the answer as it was slight wrong. There should be no need to add position relative to the parent.